# Failed to load Gradle project gluon mobile project in NetBeans

Tags: java, gradle, mobile, netbeans, gluon

### Issue 1

Requested project: C:\Users\M6\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GluonApplication

Stack trace:
    org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip'.
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:137)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.loadModelWithProgress(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:578)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.fixProjectLoadKey(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:385)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader.access$1500(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:74)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.model.DefaultGradleModelLoader$7.run(DefaultGradleModelLoader.java:441)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.runNonBlockingGradleTask(GradleDaemonManager.java:35)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager.access$100(GradleDaemonManager.java:22)
        at org.netbeans.gradle.project.tasks.GradleDaemonManager$2.execute(GradleDaemonManager.java:125)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$FunctionWrapper.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:270)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.AbstractTaskExecutorService$TaskOfAbstractExecutor.execute(AbstractTaskExecutorService.java:340)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.Tasks$RunOnceCancelableTask.execute(Tasks.java:342)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.runTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:919)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$QueuedItem.access$1200(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:898)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.executeTask(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:815)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.processQueue(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:827)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$Worker.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:861)
        at org.jtrim.concurrent.SingleThreadedExecutor$Impl$1.run(SingleThreadedExecutor.java:453)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:225)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:155)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:169)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:131)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DistributionFactory$ZippedDistribution$1.call(DistributionFactory.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more

Comment: Please describe in more detail your settings: OS, Java version, NetBeans version, post your `build.gradle` and the file in your project `/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Comment: Also try to run in command line from the root of your project `./gradlew --info clean build run`, and see if that works

Comment: Here are settings :
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------
NetBeans :    8.2

Build time:   2017-10-02 15:36:21 UTC
Revision:     a88ebd6be7840c2e59ae4782eb0f27fbe3405ddf

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: It seems you are running on Java 9? For now you need Java 8. Until [GluonVM](http://gluonhq.com/gluon-vm-status-update/) becomes available, you can't use 9.

Comment: Install JDK8, if you don't have it yet, and make sure NetBeans starts with it as default (edit `/etc/netbeans.conf` file under Program files/NetBeans) and set `netbeans_jdkhome` to the JDK8 path.

Comment: netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151". </br> this is in the netbeans.conf file

Comment: Ok, I've edited your question to include your initial message, the settings and the build.gradle.

Comment: Go to NetBeans->Tools->Options, select Miscellaneous tab, then Gradle, and click on `Prefer wrapper`. I suggest you restart NetBeans. Then try to run the project again, and if it fails, post the relevant stacktrace.

Comment: It dosen't work...

Comment: It doesn't help that on editing your question you remove all the previous content ...

Comment: Can you try to run this from command line, from the root of the project: `gradlew --info clean build run`. See if that works.

Comment: oh, sorry. I told you that's my first time I use this platform. So, I ask you to be patient with me. Really sorry... So, how can I run this command please ?

Comment: Command line? Search for `cmd` on Windows, then navigate to your project, and type the command.

Comment: Hi sir José, I've separately downloaded the gradle 2.14.1 all.zip. So howcan I install it and where? Thanks very much, Kindly..

Comment: If you run `gradlew` (w stands for *wrapper*), it will download and install it for you, so you don't have to worry about that. If you want to install it though, just do it as a regular application, or simply extract it in a folder.

Comment: It works !!! :D Thanks so much, José Pereda. Sorry for the late, I was in travelling...